# Simple VBA to inserting row at an increment

Tags: vba, excel

It has been awhile since I start to use VBA again.

I have one question regarding inserting row at an increment of "0.1"

The increment only applies to case when Length > "0.1"

====================================================

When new row has been insert

Write ID , Route_ID , NEW Begin_Point, NEW End_Point, NEW Length (NEW End_Point - NEW Begin_Point)

Insert row until the length is < "0.1"

====================================================

Please help me out on this or address me to any vba code that would get this done. The specify question as well as the format for the desire answer are below.

I really appreciate your help!

> **Question**
>
> **ID** | **Route_ID** | **Begin_Point** | **End_Point** | **Length** |
>
> 1105 | A_ST | 1.166 | 1.271 | 0.105
>
> 99 | C_BLVD | 0 | 0.08 | 0.08
>
> 24 | B_AVE | 0.447 | 0.627 | 0.18
>
> **Desired Answer**
>
> **ID** | **Route_ID** | **Begin_Point** | **End_Point** | **Length** |
>
> 1105 | A_ST | 1.166 | 1.266 | 0.1
>
> 1105 | A_ST | 1.266 | 1.271 | 0.005
>
> 99 | C_BLVD | 0 | 0.08 | 0.08
>
> 24 | B_AVE | 0.447 | 0.547 | 0.1
>
> 24 | B_AVE | 0.547 | 0.627 | 0.08

Comment: We are not here to write code for you. And what does c++ and mysql and excel have to do with vba?

Comment: This looks like it could use some factoring by using Normal Forms.  What are the key fields?

Comment: Are the '|' characters part of the input?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews is not a part of the input, the key fields is the ID, Begin, End, Length. Thanks for your help

Comment: @MarcB I understood that but if you can provide me some input on how to start that would be great as well. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged your question with `c++`, I'm assuming you want C++ language help with this.

Let's start with a structure that defines the record:

```
struct Record
{
    unsigned int id;
    std::string  route_id;
    double       begin_point;
    double       end_point;
    double       length;
};
```

My understanding is that you are to generate new segments until all segments are less than or equal to 0.1 in length.

For convenience, let's store the records into a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Record> table;
```

Let's assume that the variable `entry` is read from the database (excel or mysql).

A `while` loop could be used to create multiple segments:

```
Record entry; 
// Input the entry here.
//...
while (entry.length > 0.1)
{
  Record segment = entry; // Make a copy to generate a new segment.
  if (segment.length > 0.1)
  {
    segment.length = 0.1;
    entry.length -= 0.1;
    segment.end_point = segment.begin_point + segment.length;
    entry.begin_point = segment.end_point;
    table.push_back(segment);
  }
}
table.push_back(entry);
```

*Note: above code has not been thoroughly tested and is provided for concept purposes only to demonstrate a possible algorithm.*